# Library for static System.Data.Linq.DataContext

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

i need to write a library (dll) in c# to handle correctly multiple instances of DataContext.

This library must be written for a global using (web, console, etc..).

On a my old DB library, i create a type with private costructor, and a static property, for simplify my projects

An example:

```
public class DbClass
{
    private DbClass() { }

    private static DbClass instance;
    public static DbClass Instance
    {
        get
        {
            if (DbClass.instance == null)
                DbClass.instance = new DbClass();
            return DbClass.instance;
        }
    }
}
```

An example of use:

```
public void Update()
{
    DbClass.Instance.ExecuteSql("UPDATE Users SET IsUpdated = 'True'");
}
```

This class stored only a string (connectionString) into its static instance: no problems in web context, no problems in console context.

But i need to reuse this concept with linq-to-sql, by extending the DataContext type.

Any ideas?

**EDIT:**

By the first comment of Grant Thomas, i think my request is not explained good, and maybe my bad english not help..

I need to write a .Net Library (dll) to manage DB Data by a static DataContext Property:

this property must detect the current Context (web, windows MTA Thread, windows STA Thread)

and create/reuse instances of DataContext without throwing ThreadExceptions or others conflicts.

A sort of DataContextFactory...

Any comments/ideas was appreciated

Comment: Would not go there if I were you. Read http://www.west-wind.com/weblog/posts/2008/Feb/05/Linq-to-SQL-DataContext-Lifetime-Management

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, If I gave you the best answer you might as well choose me...

Would not go there if I were you. Read http://www.west-wind.com/weblog/posts/2008/Feb/05/Linq-to-SQL-DataContext-Lifetime-Management

Answer (score 0):

You can extend your DataContext easily enough by creating another file under the same namespace:

```
namespace MyDataContextNamespace {
  public partial class MyDataContext { 

  }
}
```

Then you can expose your singleton from there.

Comment: This is my first idea for mantain concept. But a static variable of DataContext type haven't only a string stored into its instance, and throws ThreadException when called by 2 iis threads, for example.

Comment: No idea what that sentence means, but of course a singleton isn't going to work inherently in a web environment - each request will spawn a new context (which probably won't be getting disposed as you'e expecting to be using the same one). This answer provides a way for your to 'extend' the data context exactly in the way you're doing now, but doesn't fix your existing problems (yes, your current implementation suffers the same).

Comment: I need to reuse the same concept (static variable), not to extend the DB class. My first idea replace the private static variable with a object into HttpContext.Current.Session. if ( HttpContext.Current != null && HttpContext.Current.Session["dataCtx"] == null) ...etc. This is a correct way to implement it in web context? And in console multithread context, what i can use?